# How to use Custom colors and custom Fonts in Itext7

Tags: itext, itext7

I am using IText7 to generate pdf from html string. 
Now I have requirements to apply custom colors and custom Fonts or Font families to the paragraphs.

How it can be done with Itext7?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

## Custom fonts:

This is explained in many different iText 7 tutorials:

- [Introducing fonts](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1) in the Building Blocks tutorial,
- [Using fonts in pdfHTML](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml) in the HTML to PDF tutorial.

**An example:**

suppose that you have a font program for the Cardo Regular font:

```
public static final String REGULAR =
    "src/main/resources/fonts/Cardo-Regular.ttf";
```

You can create a `FontProgram` object with this font program like this:

```
FontProgram fontProgram =
    FontProgramFactory.createFont(REGULAR);
```

With this `FontProgram` object, you can create a `PdfFont`:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(
    fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
```

Now you can use this `PdfFont` object to change the font of a paragraph:

```
p.setFont(font);
```

This is only one way to use a custom font; you'll find other ways in the tutorials. Surely you understand that it doesn't make sense to copy a tutorial into a Stack Overflow answer.

## Custom Colors

iText 7 has a class called `Color`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/colors/Color.html

This class has several subclasses: `CalGray`, `CalRgb`, `DeviceCmyk`, `DeviceGray`, `DeviceN`, `DeviceRgb`, `IccBased`, `Indexed`, `Lab`, `PatternColor`, `Separation`.

You can create a custom color by choosing one of those subclasses, depending on the colorspace you are working in. For instance: suppose that you want to use a device RGB color, then you'd use the `DeviceRgb` class.

**An example:**

Suppose that you want an RGB color with values red = 0.2, green = 0.2, blue = 0.2, then you would use this constructor: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/colors/DeviceRgb.html#DeviceRgb-float-float-float-

```
Color color = new ColorRgb(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
```

This is just one example. ISO 32000-2 will give you more info on the differences between color spaces (needed to choose the right color class) and the API documentation will explain how the different constructors work.