# Adding New font in IText 7

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to setup a new font in Itext7 and it is not reflecting in the PDF.

Adding the default font works but unable to set new fonts.

```
private static final String BRUSHED_SCRIPT = "src/main/resources/fonts/LucyTheCatRegular-Bg9x.ttf";

private PdfFont brushedScriptFont = null;

public PDFService() {
    try {
        this.brushedScriptFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(BRUSHED_SCRIPT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

private Cell getAddressCell(String text, TextAlignment alignment) throws IOException {
    Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(text).setFont(brushedScriptFont));
    cell.setPadding(0);
    //cell.setFont(this.brushedScriptFont);
    cell.setTextAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setFontSize(14);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: *"it is not working"* - in which way?

Comment: Have you tried `new Paragraph(text.setFont(brushedScriptFont))`, i.e. applying the font to the text before adding it to the paragraph?

Comment: @mkl, There is no such way to set font in iText 7.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought `text` was an iText `Text` instance but it is actually a Java `String`. In that case try `new Paragraph(new Text(text).setFont(brushedScriptFont))`, i.e. first create a `Text` instance from that `text` string, give it a font, and add it as such to the `Paragraph`.

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Though I might be misunderstanding, this is something that I seem to have working in IText7.

I initially used this StackOverFlow reference:
// [How to use Custom colors and custom Fonts in Itext7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369060/how-to-use-custom-colors-and-custom-fonts-in-itext7)

I might have varied it some to get it working for me.

If this doesn't work for you, I'll try to monitor this page, and see if I can add anything.  Added Arial font in my case.  I also 'added' 'fontawesome', but don't seem to have experimented with it.  About to do that.  Not expecting good results there, but... wouldn't mind being pleasantly surprised.  :)

Update: got fontawesome working too.  Allows display of 'checkboxes' and 'unchecked boxes' (more true to the site than a simple 'Y' 'N' display).  There are other stackoverflow answers where this is discussed, but perhaps not specifically for IText7.  If you need details, I'll add my solution here.

Sincerely,
Michael M.
UT System developer